# How to delete with using a button in Django

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I have a list of items.I'm displaying them using ListView. Each item in the list is in a collapsible block. I want to put two buttons in the collapsible block, one for editing the item, second is for deletion:

```
<a class='btn btn-success' style = 'float:left;' href="/scale/{{scale.pk}}/">Edit Scale</a>
<a class='btn btn-danger' style = 'float:right;' href="/scales" name="delete_btn">Delete Scale</a>
```

No problem with the Edit button. When it is clicked, it goes to another page with a different template and a different class (which extends to UpdateView) in the views.py.

But I can't figure out how to do delete objects with using delete button. 
I don't want to go to another page when I click on delete button, so I don't need a separate template.

I tried to extend my class to DeletionMixin:

```
class ScaleListView(DeletionMixin, ListView):
    context_object_name = 'Scales'
    model = Scale
    success_url = reverse_lazy('scale_list')

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'post in scale list'
        return DeletionMixin.post(self, *args, **kwargs)           

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        print 'get_context_data in ScaleListView'
        context = super(ScaleListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['header_name'] = 'Scale list'
        return context
```

I tried to override the post and delete methods of Deletionmixin, but I really don't know how to relate the delete button to here.

I read [this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/class-based-views/mixins/), warning says, not all mixins and class-based views can be used together. But I don't think the issue is that here.

Can someone explain how to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple problems.

First, your return statement in post() is creating a separate DeletionMixin instance, which means it will not be able to reference any fields or methods of your ScaleListView instance. You'd need something like this:

```
return super(ScaleListView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

But that won't fix your problem. DeletionMixin calls get_object(), which neither ListView nor any of its parents implements. DeletionMixin assumes you're only going to be deleting one object at a time (which is what it sounds like you're trying to do). Try using DetailView instead of ListView and see where that gets you.

(Why DetailView, when you're using a list? Because you don't want the view doing anything to the entire list. You're only dealing with an individual record (i.e., a "detail"), so that's why this makes more sense.)